# How to fix my loops for being able to count the elements of the list and the elements of the list is the list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to calculate the number of elements in a list including the elements in the lists' list.

Here is my code

---

```
my_list = [1,[2,3],[4,5,6]]
sum = 0
for x in my_list:
    for i in mylist:
        sum = sum+1
print(sum)
```

---

Comment: Do you want to allow deep nesting of many lists within each other?  Or only two levels of lists as shown here?

Comment: Did you try to _flatten_ your list and count those elements?

Comment: I am trying to do as many levels

Comment: Your expected output is one value, the sum of all integers?

Comment: [how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Do you want to **sum** values or **count** values? You say the one and your variable names suggest the other (btw. you are shadowing the built in `sum`)

Comment: @Seymour another solution to consider https://repl.it/@downshift/CoordinatedZestyStrategy

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...you need to check the data types:

```
my_list = [1,[2,3],[4,5,6]]
sum = 0
for x in my_list:
    if type(x) == list:
        sum += len(x)
    else:
        sum += 1
print(sum)
```

Comment: He wrote "I am trying to calculate the number of elements" so that's where I went with it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger variablenames and text of OP tells different things....

Comment: @user212514: Ah, true. The code and names are at odds. Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 1):

```py
my_list = [1,[2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(sum(len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 1 for x in my_list))
```

Comment: does only 1 level of nesting

Answer (score 1):

Biggest thing to note is that your my_list contains values of different types. e.g, (list, int). Therefore you need to do type checking.

To handle nested lists you will need to create a recursive function.

*Example using python 3.6+*

```
def sum_mylist(my_list: list) -> int:
    total = 0
    for i in my_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            total += sum_mylist(i)
        if isinstance(i, int):
            total += i
    return total


def main():
    my_list = [1,[2,3,4], 5, [4,5,6], [1, [2,3,4]]]
    total = sum_mylist(my_list)
    print(total) // prints 40
main()
```

UPDATED as per @ShadowRanger comments.

Comment: will only do 1 level of nesting

Comment: This is on the right track, though the OP's comments indicate they want to handle arbitrarily nested lists (so the outer `list` might contain one or more inner `list`s, which themselves contain one or more inner `list`s, ad infinitum). You'd need to recurse to handle that (replacing your call to `sum` with a recursive call to `sum_mylist`). Side-note: You usually want `isinstance(i, list)`, and even if you insist on exact types, the correct check in that case is `type(i) is list`, not `type(i) == list` (classes are singletons, so `is` is the correct test to stick to cheap identity tests).

Comment: Updated @ShadowRanger